# Handling JSON Object Array

Tags: javascript, json

I got a realy  simple question:

Take a look at this JSON String:

```
this.objects = [{"pid":"2","x":"10","y":"10"}]; // only one i know
```

Now i would like to adress an object out of it like so:

```
 this.objects.pid[2]
```

I know thats pointless in this case as you would access it like:

```
 this.objects[0]
```

The thing is that i need to adress an object array in JSON by the object id and not the array index. Is there a nice approach to this?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't understand the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getObject(id, array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].pid ==  id) {
             return array[i]
        }
    }
}
```

A function that takes your id and array and returns your object. Basically loop through the array and find the element with your id. This can be optionally cached for speed increase.

Comment: shure this works, thanks. i just replaced the for with
for (var i = 0; i < this.objects.length; i++) {

Comment: @Mike can't believe I wrote `i < 0`. Thanks for spotting that. Your supposed to call `getObject(2, this.objects)`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need to be a single element array, so try this...

```
this.objects = {"pid":"2", "x":"10", "y":"10"};
```

And you can read it either of these ways:

```
this.objects.pid;
this.objects['pid'];
```

If you wanted multiple lists of x,y,etc. then try something like this:

```
this.objects = { "2": {"x": "10", "y": "10"} };
this.objects["2"].x;
this.objects["2"]["x"];
```

Essentially, in this case, just use the "pid" as they key for each object that contains the properties you want for each item.

Comment: thanks, that would work for shure, but i want to save performance on the server side, so i would rather use the clent side approach from Raynos. Original data comes from a db over codeigniter.